# CakePHP form - remove month field name

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, stripe-payments, field-names

I'm setting up a Stripe payment form, so I need to remove the names of my month and year fields so they aren't sent to my server. The following code though, still gives the field a name of '[month]' and if the text of the array's name variable were 'xyz', the field would be named 'xyz[month]'. How can I remove the entirety of the field's name?

```
echo $this->Form->month('expiration_month', array('name' => '', 'data-stripe' => 'exp_month', 'default' => 'January'));
```

Comment: Unset ```$this->request->data['expiration_month]``` before calling Stripe api http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-month-inputs), the name of the `<select>` element is derived from the first function argument ("expiration_month" in your example.) If you take a look at [the code](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/source-class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#2051-2079), you can see the value "month" is hard-coded.

The only way around this is to manually build your own `<select>` element, or just ignore the value when it comes to your server. But why make users fill out a form element that isn't going to be processed by your server?

Comment: It isn't going to my server because it's being sent directly to Stripe. This way you don't have to worry about PCI compliance on credit card data.

Comment: But if you aren't sending a `name` attribute, it won't be processed by *any* server because it won't get sent by the browser.

Answer (score -1):

So, the quick and dirty way around this is to find the select field with js and overwrite the name attribute.